# About Fasting in the current month

Tags: sawm, ramadan

I've been fasting and its been wonderful obeying Allah's commands.I love Allah greatly.

However, when I fast I am negatively affected by health conditions beyond my control and some of my problems are lifelong.
Is there a way to pay or offer compensation for not fasting.
Currently, my fasts are being broken due to vomiting.

Answer (score 0):

It's an between you and your ALLAH for life long health problems.under certain condition you will pray fast later.

Answer (score 0):

If you are vomiting deliberately, your fasting is vanished. Although you don't have to feed poor because you have broken your fast and you have to fast another day instead. But if it is not deliberately, on the one side, if fasting makes you vomit more than usual you HAVE to stop fasting and continue it whenever you are freed from the disease (maybe you won't be able to break free from it for the rest of your live although I wish your disease fade away soon). On the other side if fasting won't affect how much you vomit during the day, your fasting will be accepted by the ALLAH and and you must continue it to the end of the day.